# The XAML Hot Reload function in Visual Studio 2022 is not working in .xaml files

Tags: .net, xaml, visual-studio-2022, maui, hot-reload

The XAML Hot Reload doesn't work for XAML files. I'm trying to simply change a  text, and when I save and/or click on the Hot Reload button, the output says "No changes to code were made.". It does work for .xaml.cs but not .xaml. My project is barebones with the basic project template for .NET MAUI that invites you to click a button. The in-app toolbar also doesn't appear.

I have followed every steps from [this page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/xaml/hot-reload?view=net-maui-7.0&tabs=vswin) along with the more extensive troubleshooting page, with no luck.

I have tried launching the project as an admin, with no success. There is no error messages in my XAML code (since I have not changed it except for the text string) and there is no error messages from the Hot Reload. The only output from Hot Reload is "No changes to code were made." I have never seen the in-app toolbar.

Changes to the XAML can only be seen after closing and opening back up the window.

I am running Visual Studio 2022(net7.O-windows10.O.19041.O), everything is up to date with no updates available.

Comment: May I know what's the version of your Visual Studio 2022? This can be checked by Open Help->About Microsoft Visual Studio.

Comment: I am on Visual Studio 2022 Community version 17.4.4

Answer (score 0):

To begin with, you can walk through [Troubleshooting XAML Hot Reload](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/visualstudio-docs/blob/main/docs/xaml-tools/xaml-hot-reload-troubleshooting.md).

In addition, please upgrade your `Visual Studio 2022` to the latest version which may resolve the The XAML Hot Reload issue.

Furthermore, if above workarounds still don't work, I suggest you directly [report](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/VisualStudio/report) it to VS Product Team, from VS > Help > Send Feedback > Report a Problem

Comment: I will report a problem to the team because as stated in my question, I am on the latest Visual Studio 2022 Version and I've done everything on the troubleshooting page.
Thank you for your help.

Comment: @etienneoh May I confirm did the hot reload work before? Or failed to work when upgrading to ` 17.4.4 `?

Comment: It has sadly never worked with .XAML files before or after.

Comment: It's a `Visual Studio` issue, you'll receive a confirmation email with a link for the submitted problem after reporting it.